# A Problem in Convergence of Sequences of Random Variables

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\left( X_n \right)$ be a sequence of independent random variables on the measure space $(\Omega, \xi,\mathbb{P})$ with 
$$ \mathbb{P} \left( X_n=1 \right)= p_n   \text{ and } \ \mathbb{P} \left( X_n=0 \right)= 1- p_n.  $$
I have proved that 
$$ X_n \to 0 \text{ in probability}\Leftrightarrow p_n \to 0 , \text{ as } \ n\to \infty $$
and 
$$ X_n \to 0 \text{ in the $L^p$ meaning of convergence} \Leftrightarrow p_n \to 0 , \text{ as } n \to \infty$$
My problem is to show the following implication:
$$ X_n \to 0 \text{ almost surely} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty. $$
I have some problem to make out what is the set 
$$ \{ w\in \Omega \ s.t. \ X_n(w) \nrightarrow 0   \} $$

Thanks in advance.

**Notation**: I'm using the notation and the definitions about convergence as in the book *Probability* by A.N. Shiryaev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Borel Cantelli lemma, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n = \infty$ then

$$P(X_n = 1 \ \  \textrm{infinitely often}) = 1.$$

But clearly

$$\{X_n = 1 \ \  \textrm{infinitely often}\}  \subseteq \{X_n \nrightarrow 0\}$$

So the latter set also has probability $1$. Hence $P(X_n \rightarrow 0) = 0$.

I have shown the contrapositive statement to your required result; the result is therefore proved.